# Running tests from JAR dependency

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I'm working on creating a JAR with my test code and planning to run the test from a different project.

Below is the approach I'm trying to implement.

Project B:

```
configurations { testApi }
task testJar ....
artifacts { testApi testJar }
```

Project A:

```
dependencies {
    testRuntime "xx.xxx.xxx.projectName", configuration: "integtest";
}
```

The test seems to be not running with this approach. Any idea on what could be the issue? Any better approaches?

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more, e. g. what is "not running" what error do you get, etc.

Comment: When i run `gradle test` the test classes are not getting recognized from the jar. But the build completes successfully

Answer (score 2):

Gradle only looks for test classes in the directories configured via `testClassesDirs` property of the respective `Test`-type task which with the `java` plugin is `project.sourceSets.test.output.classesDirs` for the `test` task. Running tests from JAR files in dependencies is not supported.

You need to extract the JAR file and add the extracted directory to this property. I think something like the following construct should work, I didn't test it though:

```
configurations {
    externalTests
}
dependencies {
    externalTests "xx.xxx.xxx.projectName", configuration: "integtest"
    testRuntime "xx.xxx.xxx.projectName", configuration: "integtest"
}
test {
    // if only one dependency in externalTests you can use the simpler, it will fail if there are multiple dependencies
    testClassesDirs += zipTree(configurations.externalTests.singleFile)
    // if multiple dependencies in externalTests you need to use
    testClassesDirs += configurations.externalTests.files.collect { zipTree it }.sum()
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vampire, I'm encountering `initializationError` `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` when trying the above approach, I'm guessing that it's not recognizing the classes. any ideas? I tried unpacking the JAR and set the `testClassesDir = files("${buildDir}/integTest/classes/java")`. That too resulted in same error.

Comment: Then put it to the classpath too like you originally did, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Seems like this isn't working too. Any suggesting on using the extracted files from JAR, I'm trying to use like `testClassesDir = files("${buildDir}/integTest/classes/java")`, which is also resulting in same error.

Comment: Besides that `testClsssesDir` (without trailing s) is deprecated, make sure your `testJar` task behaves nicely. What is the structure in that file and what is the exact error message including class name?